# Who sabotaged ED-209?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

in the 1987 Robocop Movie when Dick Jones introducing the His Robot ED-209 & Demonstrating to OCP chairman & Other Staff, ED-209 Kills Innocent Employee Without a Gun.. so my question is is this Malfunction of ED-209 Sabotage by **"Bob Morton"** to Get Approval from OCP to His Project Robocop or it's Just a Malfunction ED-209?

Comment: My answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64846/20774) makes mention of the reason for the failure of the ED-209 to recognise that the gun had been dropped; that it fell onto a thick carpet.

Comment: can you people understand What im asking here? im asking some other thing your saying some other thing.. please read the question carefully..i'm asking here Malfunction of ED-209 got to do anything with "Bob Morton"

Comment: You're asking why ED-209 went crazy. The answer is in the dupe. It didn't hear the gun drop and continued to treat the exec as a criminal with a gun. There's no evidence of anything other than the incompetence of the technicians and a premature demonstration that never should have gone ahead

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a duplicate. The other question asks why live ammo was loaded. That's a different question than why ED-209 malfunctioned. The top answer in the duplicate explains that live ammo was loaded **so that an error wouldn't occur.** This question is asking why an error occured anyway. I don't think the answer is very complicated, but I also don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @RANSARA009 if you don't think it's a duplicate, why did you vote to close it as one?

Comment: @hantom its already some one marked as duplicate. people coming & down voting..  before more happend that i also marked as duplicate

Comment: I don't feel like this is a duplicate, on the other hand, I don't accept the premise of the question, unless there is something somewhere that suggests ED-209 was tampered with resulting in the malfunction.

Comment: Not a dupe, and the fact that the answer is "no-one" doesn't make it a bad question :)

Comment: Bob Morton can be seen getting nervous when they say they are going to conduct "a citizen's arrest test"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as we know, it was just a malfunction.

You might apply [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) to the situation:

> Hanlon's razor is an aphorism expressed in various ways including
>   "Don't assume bad intentions over neglect and misunderstanding",
>   "Never assume malice when stupidity will suffice", and "**Never
>   attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by
>   carelessness**". It recommends a way of eliminating unlikely
>   explanations for a phenomenon (a philosophical razor).

(emphasis mine)

In other words, we have no reason to believe that anybody sabotaged ED-209. Instead, the accident can be explained by rushed development, poor planning, improper testing, etc.

You could go a step further and say that this is part of the satirical nature of the movie, criticizing business practices that favor profit over the safety of the general public, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: From the reactions in that scene, it looks like Morton simply grabbed an opportunity that had suddenly and violently presented itself. There is nothing to suggest he was prepared for the malfunction.

Comment: @JohnSensebe Yep, exactly.

Comment: Bob Morton can be seen getting nervous when they say they are going to conduct "a citizen's arrest test"